# How to get minutes from time string in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

How to get minutes from time string in javascript or jquery?

ex: if my input time is "12:30 am" then my output should be 750 min.

Comment: What hour is 12:30 am? 13:30? 00:30?

Comment: @Ganesh little confusion...How to correlate `"12:30 am"` with `750 min`.

Comment: you need 750 min in 12.30 am and 12.30 pm ?, i think it is not a right way , 12.30 am means 30 min and 12.30 pm  is 750 min

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var time="12:30 am";
var timeArray = time.split(" ");
timeArray = timeArray[0].split(":");
alert(parseInt(timeArray[0])*60+parseInt(timeArray[1]));
```

Comment: i think you need to change the thired line to  timeArray = timeArray[0].split(":");

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/32ecwdwh/

```
var time="12:30 pm";
var hr,min;
time = time.split(" ");
if(time[1]==='am'){
  time = time[0].split(":");
  hr= parseInt(time[0])-12;
  var min= parseInt(time[1]);
}
else{
  time = time[0].split(":");
  hr= parseInt(time[0]);
  min= parseInt(time[1]);
}
var date= new Date();
date.setHours(hr);
date.setMinutes(min);
alert(date.getHours()*60 + date.getMinutes());
```

Comment: Ho do you get 12 and 30 from string ?

Comment: what about 12.30 am ??

Comment: @Alexander I assumed input from Date object not as string..i should have extracted first hours and minutes..

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar but in question, input as string "12:30 am"

Answer (score 0):

Try this like,

```
var t='12:30 am';
var pat= /\d+/g;
var arr=(t.match(pat));
if(arr[0] && arr[1]){
   alert(parseInt(arr[0]*60) + parseInt(arr[1]));
}
```

```js
var t='12:30 am';
var pat= /\d+/g;
var arr=(t.match(pat));
if(arr[0] && arr[1]){
  alert(parseInt(arr[0]*60) + parseInt(arr[1]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Function with regular expression:

```js
function my_timestringToMin(input){
    input = input.match(/^(\d+)[:\.](\d+) ?(am|pm)?$/i);
    /* Convert input to array: [input, hours, minutes, am/pm/undefined] */

    var output = parseInt(input[2]); // minutes
        output += parseInt(input[1] * 60); // add hours * 60

    if(input[1] < 12 && input[3] == "pm") 
        output += 12*60; // if PM, add 12h

    return output;
}

$("#submit").click(function(){$("#result").html(my_timestringToMin($("#input").val()).toString());});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input type="text" id="input" value="12:30 am"><input id="submit" type="submit" value="calculate"></div>
<div>Result: <span id="result">750</span> min</div>
```

#### Features:

- Works with 0-filled hours: "1:00 am" = "01:00 am"
- AM/PM is optional: "13:00" = "1:00 pm"
- Space between hours and am/pm is optional: "00:00am" = "00:00 am"
- Ignores PM for hours greater than 11: "13:00pm" = "13:00" (intuitive common error solution for people using 24h clock)
- Case insensitive: "12:30 am" = "12:30 AM"
- Recognizes dot as well as colon: "12:30 am" = "12.30 am"

Answer (score 0):

First of all i can say this is not a right way.

How we can say 12.30 am is 750 minute ? i think 12.30 pm is 750 minute and 12.30 am is 30 minute ,

anyway as-per your question you can do something like below it will give the result what you ask

```
   var time="12:30 am"
   var time = time.split(" ");

    time = time[0].split(":");
    alert(parseInt(time[0])*60+parseInt(time[1]));
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kd6b4a8s/)**

Answer (score 0):

If you create your date using new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);* you can use d.getHours(); and d.getMinutes();**

EG:

```js
var date = new Date(2015, 2, 11, 12, 30, 00);
var hours = date.getHours();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
var totalMinutes = hours * 60 + date.getMinutes();
$('#time-in-minutes').html(totalMinutes);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="time-in-minutes"/>
```

*http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp
**http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getminutes.asp